# how to save and read binary information in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, binary-data

I am processing an image and want to save the result into binary ubit1 file, but I am getting unexpected results.

```
    >> fid=fopen('test.test','w');
    >> fwrite(fid,'100101','ubit1');
    >> fclose(fid);
    >> fid=fopen('test.test','r');
    >> A=fread(fid,'ubit1');
    A =
         1
         1
         1
         1
         1
         1
         0
         0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ware using char input arguments. Using a logical column vector produces the expected results.

```
fwrite(fid,logical([1 0 0 1 0 1])','ubit1');
```

The returned vector is `[1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]` because the byte must be filled.